# call powershell function with parameters

Tags: html, windows, powershell, parameters, web

I am just getting started with Windows Powershell and I am try to create a function that parses a webpage. I have tested the individual calls in the function and they seem to be working correctly. Here is the function I have created.

```
function GoTo-Website ([string]website = "google.com")
{
     $ie.navigate($website);

     $image = @($ie.Document.getElementByName("main_image"))[0].href;

     $title = @($ie.Document.getElementByTagName("h1"))[3].innerHTML;

     $date = @($ie.Document.getElementByTagName("h3"))[0].innerHTML;
}
```

This is stored in powershellScript.ps1 in the current powershell directory.

The best error I can get when I call this function is

function goto-website "Website"

Missing function body in function declaration. At line:1 char:23 + function goto-website <<<< "website" + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFunctionBody

Is there anyway to modify my code to get pass this parser error?

I also was wondering if their is a way to call a function without putting "function" before the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this modified version of your code

```
function GoTo-Website
{
    Param ($website)
    $ie.navigate($website);
    $image = @($ie.Document.getElementByName("main_image"))[0].href;
    $title = @($ie.Document.getElementByTagName("h1"))[3].innerHTML;
    $date = @($ie.Document.getElementByTagName("h3"))[0].innerHTML;
}
```

which you can call with

```
GoTo-Website "http://www.google.com"
```

or

```
GoTo-Website -website "http://www.google.com/"
```

No need to put "function" before the call.

See [today's post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/20/use-strict-mode-for-powershell-to-help-you-write-good-code.aspx) on the Scripting Guy Blog for a little more information on functions.

Comment: Yes. After changing how the parameters are called, **realizing I had to copy and paste my code into powershell**, and make my variables global to expose the results, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After following advice on how to add parameters [and realizing I have to copy and paste my function into powershell] I was able to call my function. Here is the modified version of the function

```
function GoTo-Website

{ Param ($website)

  $global:ie.navigate($website);

  $global:image = @($ie.Document.getElementById("comic_image"))[0].href;

  $global:title = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("h1"))[3].innerHTML

  $global:date = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("h3"))[0].innerHTML;

}
```

I also had to change my parameters to global to expose the results and access an internet explorer variable that is activated.